# Добавить своё расширения файла в проект VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, файлы

Добрый день,

хочу добавить новое расширения файла для студии Visual Studio 2013.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил везде, где требует msdn новое расширение .fwd - но intellisense не видит этот файл и в Solution Explorer файл без иконки. Хотелось бы и то, и то.

P.S. До этого работал с classname_fwd.h (файл с Forward Declaration and typedef's). Сейчас решил перейти на "официально оформленные отношения" с данным расширением класса. Насколько чревато это будет?
Зарание спасибо!

Comment: Вы всё слишком усложняете. Не надо изобретать типы файлов только ради их классификации, если они обрабатываются идентично с уже существующим типом. Что дурного в `class_fwd.h`, `class.fwd.h` и т. п.?

Comment: ради семантики. cpp / h / inl(templates) / fwd(forward declaration). Насчёт class.fwd.h не уверен, что будет отрабатыватся на других платформах (iOS, Mac, Android)

Comment: Под виндой строго определено, что расширением является секция после последней точки. Подозреваю, что линуксоидные инструменты действуют согласно такой же логике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить файл с произвольным расширением можно в три шага:

1. Открываем свойства файла через контекстное меню и выставляем `тип элемента` в `Заголовок C/C++` (нужно для сборки)

[image: контекстное меню -> свойства]

2. В параметрах среды, в разделе `текстовый редактор` добавить новое расширение для `Microsoft Visual C++` (для подсветки и `Intellisense`)

[image: Параметры среды]

3. В панели свойств файла выставляем `тип файла` в `C++ заголовочный файл` (нужно для иконки)

[image: панель свойств файла]

PS также не помешает в параметрах проекта добавить ваше расширение во `включаемые расширения`

[image: Параметры проекта]